# ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rplidar_ros/rplidarNode]: can't locate node [rplidarNode] in package [rplidar_ros]

Tags: ros, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I keep on receiving this error every time i execute roslaunch rplidar_ros view_rplidar.launch

I have executed source devel/setup.bash as well.

In addition,  rplidar_ros exists on my rospack list.

When i execute, Rviz map/grid shows up, but with no laser scans.

please help with this matter.

I am not sure what is causing the error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256509/error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Brplidar_ros/rplidarnode%5D:-can%27t-locate-node-%5Brplidarnode%5D-in-package-%5Brplidar_ros%5D/) by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2017-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-03-08**:
Check your spelling for `rplidar`. you have an additional letter i in there.

**Comment by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) on 2017-03-08**:
still doesn't work. any clues?

**Comment by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) on 2017-03-08**:
what do you think might be causing it?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-03-09**:
Please give some more information: How is your workspace set up, did you install `rplidar` from debs or from source, is it in your workspace?

My guess currently is, you installed from source and haven't compiled it.

**Comment by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) on 2017-03-09**:
Okay so it works now. I installed from source, so i needed to install rplidarNode on src.

source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
roslaunch rplidar_ros view_rplidar.launch

**Comment by [uchiha_levi](https://answers.ros.org/users/116208/uchiha_levi/) on 2022-09-02**:
I tried catkin_make in my catkin_ws many times after cloning it from git and it didn't work. But when I used

catkin_make --only-pkg-with-deps rplidar_ros

it  worked after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just do the follwoing commands:

source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash

otherwise remove the files and git clone again and run catkin_make . Works every time.

---

Originally posted by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) with karma: 96 on 2017-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1